# how to apply spartan style in tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-styles, tcolorbox

According to `tcolorbox` user manual, compilation time can benefit much from using spartan `style`. But it is not clear to me how to apply a style to the a concrete box, or to the whole document. Illustrative examples might help in doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just say `\tcbset{spartan}` to get all boxes using `spartan` or use it locally for particular boxes or in a `\newtcolorbox` definition (not shown here)

The `spartan` option is a `skin` actually, so `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` is necessary or `\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}` or `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`.

In fact `spartan` is a wrapper for `skin=spartan`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\tcbset{spartan}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  Foo
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced]
Foo
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `[most]`? It only worked for me when this was added.

Comment: @nightcod3r: It loads most of the extra `tcolorbox` libraries, especially the `skin` library -- which is needed for `spartan`. It's documented in the `tcolorbox` manual

Comment: I meant the `skins` library, not `skin`